# Is there some way to do a kind of relationship between keys in an interface in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let me try to explain. I have the follow response interface:

```
interface IResponse {
  status: "success" | "error";
  content: IMySuccessResponse | string;
}
```

Is there any way to make Typescript understand that when the status for equal to **"success"** the only possible value of content will be **"IMySuccessResponse"**, and when the status for equal to **"error"** the only possible value of content will be a **string**?

I tried something like that:

```
interface IResponse {
  response: {
    status: "success";
    content: IMySuccessResponse ;
  } | {
    status: "error";
    content: string;
  }
}
```

But the Typescript kept on understanding that both values of content are possible regardless of status value.

[image]

**EDIT =========================================================**

OMG, the issue was in the destructuring. Somehow the destructuring was messing up the Typescript, so without the destructure it's worked.

[image]

Comment: Try using two interfaces, a success and an error one. Then assign `ISuccessResponse | IErrorResponse` to your object. [Seems to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUCuCkGdcBKEuADgPYi4oDeAUMg8rmHGJrgFzIBEu2eubgG56jBBUjguITAFsARtGQiAvrVqhIsRClQBRKFDJQipClWR1GTFm049oRqMNENx4CFJtRQAcxEMarQANhBgyAAWEMHBZMhcGPzEhMTklCgAPmgGTqZpFgC8lq42rOxcvEn43AA0Je6SYFwAjABMtEFRMXFF1KV2FY7GtcgNnk08ZGQkgsgqIl2xyL395Q6GwzWjEuMtAMxzIkA)

Comment: Your second `IResponse` has only a single property, `response`. I think what you meant was `type IResponse = {…} | {…}`

Comment: Oh, well noted @Bergi! I'll refactor my code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TS only does checks at compile-time, you have to make it know what the value of status is.

The following works for me:

```js
type IMySuccessResponse = { hello: string }

interface IResponse {
  response: {
    status: "success";
    content: IMySuccessResponse ;
  } | {
    status: "error";
    content: string;
  }
}

const response: IResponse = /* ... */;

if (response.response.status === "success") {
  // inside this scope, the type of `content` is `IMySuccessResponse`.
  console.log(response.response.content.hello);
} else {
  // in this scope, `content` is a string.
  console.log(response.response.content);
  console.log(response.response.content.hello); // this, TS complains that `content` is a string
}
```

If you check for the value of `content`, within the scope of that check, TS will be clever enough to know what type it could be.

Comment: btw, if you want to look up this concept in more details, it's called a 'type guard', and it's very helpful in a lot of other situations.

Comment: I tried exactly the same one, but if in the scope of the first condition you try setting a state that expects to receive a type "IMySuccessResponse", the Typescript is gonna warn that the state isn't assignable to type "IMySuccessResponse" | string. I'll update the question with the image.

Comment: interesting, it works for me. what's your version of TS?
nvm, just saw you found a solution!